# Schedule task to delete contents from folders

Tags: batch-file, directory, delete-file, subdirectory

I want to run a job which deletes the contents of a folder every night.
The folder contains 5/6 subfolders.
Is it possible to delete from each of these sub folders but not delete the actual folders? Or do I have to run a task for each folder?

Answer (score 6):

Create a delete.bat file, put this in for every folder you want to delete from:

```
del "C:\your_folder_name\*.*"
```

Then schedule a task to run delete.bat. Or to loop folders under a certain folder and delete all those files, you can use:

```
C:\> CD \your_folder_name
C:\> FOR /D /r %G in ("*") DO del "%G" /s /Q
```

`/s` deletes from all subfolders
`/q` does it quietly (doesn't prompt for every file)
`%G` is the subfolder var

**Further Reading**:

- [SS64 - `DEL`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [How do you make a batch file to delete all files and folders in a particular folder?](https://www.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_make_a_batch_file_to_delete_all_files_and_folders_in_a_particular_folder)

Answer (score 2):

The DEL command has a /S (subfolders) option that deletes under sub-folders, but preserves the directory structure. You can combine this feature with the AT command to schedule the command to be run every day. Assuming the folder to delete files is `C:\tmp`, and you want to run the cleanup every day at 23:59, you can issue the following command.

```
AT 23:59 /EVERY:m,t,w,th,f,s,su "del C:\tmp\* /S /Q >> C:\cleanup.log"
```

It will also write the deleted filenames to `C:\cleanup.log`, since there's no other way to figure out the results of the command.

For a complete reference see [DEL](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) and [AT](http://ss64.com/nt/at.html).